# How to get a zero-based count in a Velocity foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, velocity

I am trying to get a zero-based counter in a Velocity `#foreach` directive.

if i use:

```
#foreach ($item in $list)
   item.getName() : $velocityCount
#end
```

i will get:

```
Fred : 1
Wilma : 2
Barney : 3
```

But i need:

```
Fred : 0
Wilma : 1
Barney : 2
```

The solution must be as simple as possible from the velocity template's point of view.

**EDIT**:
I can use:

```
#foreach ($item in $list)
   #set( $num = $velocityCount - 1 ) //The white space in mandatory
   item.getName() : $num
#end
```

and it works. But I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

**EDIT 2**:
I need the one-based counter to be available too. That is, in the same template i will most likely have one `#foreach` directive that will require a zero-based counter and another `#foreach` directive that requires a one-base counter.

Comment: @Rob Not that simple, apparently.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using Velocity 1.7 there are `$foreach.index` (0-based) and `$foreach.count` (1-based) special vars available inside loops.

`$velocityCount` is something that was deprecated long time ago afaik.

Comment: Good point, I had assumed < 1.7 because of the `velocityCount` reference--bad assumption!

Answer (score 8):

```
#set($i = 0)

  #foreach($str in $names)
    #set($i = $i+1)
    $i : $str
 #end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the doc](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#loops), you can specify:

```
directive.foreach.counter.initial.value = 0
```

In velocity.properties file.

Comment: Thanks, but that will deprive me from the ability to use the one-based counter. See edit2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't have both, obviously--you either need to just do the math when you're displaying, or create a [custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159292/how-do-i-create-a-custom-directive-for-apache-velocity) (and [here's the article the SO post links to](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-create-custom-directives-for-apache-velocity/)). For instance, you could have `#forEachZeroBased` and `#forEachOneBased`.

Custom directives are very useful sometimes, although IMO this isn't one of them--just do the math, it's the obvious solution, and it's just not that big of a deal.

Comment: @summerbulb Obviously I did, since I commented on it and voted it up-like I said, I assumed < 1.7 since the index/count thing is documented in the user guide.