# velocity count not incrementing in recursive call

Tags: velocity

My code looks like this:

```
#macro (myMac $listOfValues)
    #foreach ($val in ${listOfValues})
        #set ($subList = $val.child())
        #if (some condition)
            some output
            #if (${velocityCount} < ${listOfValues.size()})
               ,\n
            #end
        #else
            #myMac(${subList})  -- B
        #end
    #end
#end
#myMac (${listOfValues})  -- A
```

listOfValues -- is a list of string
subList  -- is a list of String

${listOfValues.size() is always zero, during the recursive call (call from B), though the list has more than one value. However when the macro is called from A the size is correct. Can you please point out if there is something missing...

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a similar problem, I found a post that helped with recursive macros.

Basically it suggested de-referencing the macro parameters, and using local copies instead, I believe this will solve the problem...

So try

```
#macro (myMac $listOfValues)
#set ($localValues = $listOfValues) ##dereference parameters
#foreach ($val in ${localValues})
    #set ($subList = $val.child())
    #if (some condition)
        some output
        #if (${velocityCount} < ${localValues.size()})
            ,\n
        #end
    #else
        #myMac(${subList})  -- B
    #end
#end
#end
#myMac (${listOfValues})  -- A
```

Answer (score 1):

Every call to #myMac includes a new #foreach, every #foreach sets its own $velocityCount

This is one of the reasons it is deprecated.  You can't access the $velocityCount for the parent #foreach.

In v1.7, you can use $foreach.count for the current loop and $foreach.parent.count for the parent and $foreach.parent.parent.count and so on.

Or you could just make your own counter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe velocityCount is not designed for recursive usage. Velocity has its limitations. You might easily workaround by setting your own counter.

Comment: btw $velocityCount seems to be also deprecated, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7854154/1448704